# Unable to mount Patitions in new version of ubuntu 23.10

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

When I try to open the partition it shows me this error

[image]

I tried everything like
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda2 /mnt this command works and mount the partition in mnt but when I restart the pc then same thing happened. Please help me. It was working properly before updating to 23.10

Comment: Not a Linux NTFS driver issue, but a Windows "feature". Windows default to fast boot which sets hibernation flag. And then you cannot write into NTFS formatted partitions or else you lose data when hibernation file restored in Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation